# How to login using sql password() function in laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel-5

> I want to login using the sql password() function in laravel. This is because the master database of employee table contains password in the format insert into tbl_name(' ') values (' ', password('abc'));
>   So I need to use this master table for login so can anyone suggest me as to how can this be possible?

```
    public function login(Request $request) {
        // dd($request->all());        
        if(Auth::attempt([
            'tgi' => $request->tgi,
            'password' => $request->password
        ]))
        {
            // $user = \DB::where('tgi', $request->tgi)->first();
            $user = MasterLogin::where('tgi', $request->tgi)->first();
            if($user->is_admin() == '1') {
                return redirect()->route('dashboard');
            }
            elseif($user->is_admin() == '0'){
                return redirect()->route('home');
            }
            elseif($user->is_admin() == '3'){
                return redirect()->route('manager');
            }
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    } 
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
    {
        $plain = $credentials['password'];

        return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
    }
```

> In validateCredentials i would like to know how can I pass the password here. 
>   As of now I tried this as said:

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    // dd($request->all());
    if(Auth::attempt([
        'tgi' => $request->tgi,
        'password' => sha1($request->password)
    ]))
    {           
        $user = User::select("SELECT * FROM emp_username_db WHERE tgi = $request->tgi AND password = sha1('$request->password')");
        if (Hash::check(sha1($request->password), $user['password'])) {
            // The passwords match...
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

> My code that I am working on

```
    class LoginController extends Controller
    {
        public function login(Request $request) {
             //$user = User::where('tgi', $request->tgi)->first();
$result = User::where('tgi',$request->tgi)->where('password',\DB::raw('password("$request->password")'))->exists();

            if ($result) {


      if($result->is_admin() == '1'){
                // Authentication passed...
                return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
            }elseif($result->admin == '0'){
                return redirect()->route('home');
            }
            elseif($result->admin == '3'){
                return redirect()->route('manager');
            }
            return redirect()->back();           
        }
    }
```

Comment: If your table has a password as plain text, you can just compare the password with user inputs.

Comment: @MuhammadShareyar I tried to but unable. If you could guide me then would be great. Password is in this format "*A44329DA553AC9A8C097D6D74C5453ACEED10B93"  stored in database table

Comment: I answered your question, did you check ?

Comment: @MuhammadShareyar Yes I am working on it. Will check and reply you on it.

Answer (score 0):

As SQL default password is hashed using `SHA1` so we can compare user's password by using laravel `raw` query like this.

```
$result = User::where('tgi',$request->tgi)->where('password',\DB::raw('password("$request->password")'))->exists();

if($result){
  your code....
}
```

[image: This is how I am getting now after using the above query]

> It's redirecting to dashboard but getting 302 found.

Comment: I did try it as you can see in the above login function. Still its not redirecting to dashboard view page.

Comment: I have updated the code try this one, it will work. @Shruti

Comment: show your updated code for better understanding @Shruti